# How to compile custom scss files like scss/style.scss in bootstrap4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, grunt-contrib-sass

I have successfully download and installed bootstrap dependency, And I was also able to compile scss/bootstrap.scss to dist/css/bootstrap.css file using grunt i.e. grunt watch, but when I tried to add custom 'scss/style.scss' file, grunt watch is ignoring style.scss and does not generate the dist/css/style.css

I am following the below url, for installation from source file
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/build-tools/

Comment: what error you see when you run grunt ?

Comment: I dont get any error, but when i edit scss/style.scss, dist/css/style.css is not generated

Comment: can you show what code have you written in style.scss